# is there any sublime text package rainbow brackets?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm looking for a package similar to atom [swackets](https://atom.io/packages/swackets), allowing rainbow coloring of brackets  (and eventually parentheses) regardless of language I'm using.

(note : there is a package already doing it only for [parenthesis on lips](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Rainbowth) but I it doesn't correspond to what I'm looking for)

edit : juste use VSCode.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know whether there is a package for this, but just doing it on your own should not be that hard (if you have a good syntax file).

Syntax files usually scope a brace as `meta.brace.curly` and each brace adds a meta scope `meta.group.braces.curly`.
Knowing this we can change the colorscheme. (To find your colorscheme you can use [PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer))

Just add a different color for a different number of surrounding `meta.group.braces.curly` context. For example you can add this at a reasonable position:

```xml
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Brace Level 0</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.brace.curly</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#990099</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Brace Level 1</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.group.braces.curly meta.brace.curly</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#00ccff</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Brace Level 2</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.brace.curly</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#33cc33</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Brace Level 3</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.brace.curly</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#ffff00</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Brace Level 4</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.brace.curly</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#ff00ff</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Brace Level 5</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.brace.curly</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#cc3300</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Brace Level 6</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.brace.curly</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#91e374</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Brace Level 7</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.brace.curly</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#6699cc</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Brace Level 8</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.brace.curly</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#0000cc</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Brace Level 9</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.brace.curly</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#9900ff</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Brace Level 10</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.group.braces.curly meta.brace.curly</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#6600cc</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

This results in the following highlighting:

[image: brace highlighting]

Comment: Thanks I will look into it.

Comment: Unfortunately, not all language definitions have nested bracket scopes, so this won't work for all languages.

Comment: @MattDMo Yes, that what I meant with "if you have a good syntax file", but I should have stated it clearer. Since they do a lot of syntax rewriting at the moment, I hope an increasing number of languages will support it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package for sublime text 3
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Rainbowth

Comment: The question states that it should be "regardless of the language" used. 
Rainbowth needs to be configured with a list of languages that need to match in order to work.
So it maybe good enough, but still doesn't completely solve the problem stated.

Comment: @dubrox Rainbowth is trivial to configure to add a new language (it's literally just adding the language name to its config array in the settings file), but I was unable to get it to work at all despite no errors.

Comment: @EvilJordan you might be running into the same issue described here: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/04/08/sublime-text-clojure/ 

"Rainbowth does its bracket magic by by actually modifying your color scheme file due to limitations in the plugin API in Sublime. The dilemma here, though, is that the color schemes are not easily edited by a plugin, since they are stored in ZIP archives in the Sublime Text installation folder."